# On Windows 10 taskbar, can I make multiple entries having different launch arguments to same exe?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, taskbar, arguments

One of the limitations of the post-xp Taskbar (and Start menu) is that the entries are keyed only on the exe file, and any exe can only have one entry. That means that unlike shortcuts, you can’t have multiple entries with different launch arguments. So no entries to ssh for individual hosts, no launching browsers with particular profiles etc.

One way I have worked around this this is to use symbolic links to create multiple symbolic exe files, and then create a shortcut to each one with the required command-line arguments. I wrote a powershell script to wrangle all of that.

Still, it is a bit of a mess, and software updates typically break the symbolic links, so the script must be re-run after updating.

Do the Taskbar and Start menu still have this limitation? If so, is there a better solution then multiple symbolic links?